# How can I fix the following javascript code to make it work with flowtype?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, flowtype

Given the following snippet I am getting the error below...
how should I can fix it?

> This type is incompatible with the expected
>   return type of number enum.

```
type Size = 1 | 2 | 3;
const GetSize = (): Size => {
    const result: number = parseInt(Math.random() * 20);
    if (result > 3) {
        return 3;
    }
    return result;
};
```

You can [try it online](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKAlgF4EC8YAjGAD5gBM9YAzANyp4AeOcAThjABjOADsAzkIDieDCXJgqACgCUALiJlKAPjABvVAEhRkofzwSArjAyaxVgLYAjPPyVgcAQ34S8ASTEMZQBZLwwACwA6fi8xABM4RzVkJgAGVU4jYigwZQtrWzA9VlUDYyMLDCt+MTYsgF9jKpq6gpsMTgb2IA)...

**Edit:**

The issue is related to the conversion from integer to enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to cast it because in [flow](https://flowtype.org/) `number` is not a subtype of `1 | 2 | 3`

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() returns a "floating point" number between [0, 1). So it can return 0.5 or 0.31231. The types are indeed incompatible. Even if it returned either 0 or 1 with equal probability, you'd still be outside the constraints of your Size type.

One way to fix this would be to do something like `return (int)result + 1`. But I don't know if Flow is smart enough to understand that. A proper way would be to have `if/else`s for all cases you anticipate, and explicitly return 1, 2 or 3 based on those. Like you're doing for results larger than 3.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1, it's return type is `number`.

Your defined return type is stricter than that, it's `1 | 2 | 3`. `Math.random()` doesn't comply with with the return type you defined, so it can't be returned.  That's the error.

Comment: thanks, fixing that doesn't fix flow issue, added explanation on the question.

Comment: @alejandrogarciarobles If you `return 1` instead of `return result` it works. The problem is that you're trying to return a `number` instead of something out of your enum.

Comment: exactly, I wonder why flow doesn't understand if statement below and properly casts from number to number enum.

Comment: Because `number` is not convertable to `number enum`, `number enum` is convertable to `number`.

Comment: it is not convertable because a number is not a subtype of enum.